# Discord showing two tray icons after update

Tags: icons, system-tray

This one is a bit exoteric. Recently after updating my system ('apt upgrade' and 'snap refresh') the discord app started showing two icons on the system tray instead of one. It happens only after some time after opening it, and so far I think discord is working exactly the same. So its more of an visual annoyance than anything else. If I click on any of them and select "quit discord", the app will close and both icons will disappear. Then opening the app again will only show one icon for a while.

Im still trying to investigate what exactly triggers the second icon to appear. I usually only notice it when I leave my computer for a while, and then when I come back the second icon is there. Discord is only installed via snap.

Removing it ('snap remove discord') and installing again didnt work.

Im on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Edit: I found that the trigger is having the monitors turn off (in the power settings, mine are set to turn off after 2 minutes of inactivity). When I come back and move my mouse to wake-up the monitors, the second icon is there.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YdRV.png)

Comment: I updated and y have 2 icons at the top bar . The second shows up when I come back from a suspension. I have installed discord from snap. I have no way to solve it.. i think in future updates?

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues . Then post the link to the bug report in your Question above...because I bet you're not the only person affected by this issue.

Comment: Same problem for me (from France) on Ubuntu 22.04 After locking my computer screen, I have 2 Discord tray icons, since 3 days (since last update). I tried to uninstall Discord, but same problem. Discord Team answered me : "...make sure you reinstall Discord using the download from our homepage. We also suggest going through Linux Github and installing all required files from there: https://github.com/simoniz0r/Discord-Linux-Client-Issues. Could you try the Canary version of our application? You can download here: https://discordapp.com/api/download/canary?platform=linux" I have not tried yet..

Comment: You need to provide a resolution for this to be an answer - please state if the solution worked or not.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all discord you have installed. Then-

Download discord .deb file from discord server - [Click](https://discord.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb) download will start.

Then go to the folder where you saved it. Then right-click on an empty space and click on the open in terminal.

Then write down the code bellow

sudo dpkg -i discord-0.0.20.deb

Comment: Despite everyone downvoting this answer, it actually does fix the problem. Since I installed the deb package for Discord instead of the snap version the second icon does not appear after my monitor turning off.